# Jersey - Multipart data form with text body parts

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0

I am trying to send Multipart Form into the Jersey 2.22.1 server as a POST request. This request contains file and multiple text fields. What is happening on the server side is that I can only receive file as InputStream, but all text arguments, which I'm receivin are null.

Here's what I have:

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version> <!-- Make sure the Jersey matches
                             the one you are currently using -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.mimepull</groupId>
        <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>vedica-api</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature
        </param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.nws.vedica.api,com.fasterxml.jackson</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

and code:

```
    import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;
...

@POST
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response createDocument(
           @FormDataParam("meno") String name,
            @FormDataParam("rc") String rc,
            @FormDataParam("typzml") String typzml,
            @FormDataParam("auto") String auto,
            @FormDataParam("verzia") String verzia,
            @FormDataParam("documentcustomname") String doccustomname,
            @FormDataParam("docpath") String docpath,
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream data,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileInfo
    ) {
        ...
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
```

so all the String parameters are null.

And here is screenshot of how I'm sendin the request:

[image]

can you explain what am I doing wrong and how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I think FormParam its case sensitive, maybe it doesn't have anything to do with, but have you tried matching the case on the request and @FormDAtaParam ie typzml vs TypZML

Comment: well, as you can see there are params that match exactly and then ones that match partially... all null

Answer (score 0):

okey, so I found that it was my IDE that was incorrectly creating war package. Code and dependencies are fine, but at least I have found out that parameters are case sensitive!